# Java code executed by Databricks/Spark job - settings for one executor

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

In our current system there is one Java code that is reading one file and it will generate many JSON documents for the full day - 24h; all JSON docs are written to CosmosDB. When I execute it in the console everything is OK. I have tried to schedule a Databricks job by using the uber-jar file and it failed with the following error:

```
"Resource with specified id or name already exists."
```

It seems ok... IMO because the default settings of the existing cluster contain many executors - so each executor will try to write to CosmosDB the same set of JSON docs.
So I changed the main method as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 SparkConf conf01 = new SparkConf().set("spark.executor.instances","1").set("spark.executor.cores","1");
 SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf01).getOrCreate(); 
 ...
}
```

But I received the same error *"Resource with specified id or name already exists"* from the CosmosDB.
I would like to have only one executor for this specific Java code, how to use only one spark executor?

Any help (link/doc/url/code) will be  appreciated. 
Thank you !